# Bluetooth LE scanning procedure cannot be stopped after a configuration change

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm writing a simple Android app that scans for BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) advertising packets and displays their contents on the screen. I have a Button on the screen that toggles BLE scanning: if scanning is not active, pressing the Button will start it; if it's active, it will stop it.

Starting and stopping the BLE scan works fine if no configuration change occurs. However if I start the scanning, then rotate my device and then try to stop it, nothing happens. That is, the scanning  procedure will stay active and I will still be receiving `ScanCallback`s. Pressing the Button again or rotating the device back and then pressing the Button also doesn't stop the scanning procedure.

Here's the code snippet that is responsible for BLE Scanning:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
  private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()

  private val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? by lazy {
    val bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager =
      getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
    bluetoothManager.adapter
  }
  
  private val bleScanner: BluetoothLeScanner? by lazy {
    bluetoothAdapter?.bluetoothLeScanner
  }

  private val scanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
    override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
      super.onScanResult(callbackType, result)
      
      Log.d("ScanCallBack", "${result}")
    }
  }

  @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
  private fun toggleScan() {
    if (bleScanner == null) {
      return
    }
    
    if (mainViewModel.scanActive) {
      bleScanner?.stopScan(scanCallback)
    } else {
      bleScanner?.startScan(buildScanFilters(), buildScanSettings(), scanCallback)
    }
    
    mainViewModel.scanActive = !mainViewModel.scanActive
    mainViewModel.updateScanActive(mainViewModel.scanActive)
  }

}
```

Note: all the code related to enabling Bluetooth and granting Runtime permissions is not shown.

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955768/bluetoothadapter-wont-stop-scanning-for-ble-devices) on this forum that in order to successfully stop the BLE scanning procedure, the `stopScan` function needs to be passed the same `ScanCallback` object, as the one that was passed into the `startScan` function.

Because of the configuration change (screen rotation), `MainActivity` will be recreated and all of its properties will be also reinitialized.
In my example, when I start the scanning, I pass one instance of `ScanCallback`, but after the configuration change, when I stop the scanning, I pass a different instance of `ScanCallback`.
I checked it using the `Log.d()` function and they are indeed different.

I don't know the right way how to deal with it, so I temporarily put the `ScanCallback` object into an existing `ViewModel`, so it won't get destroyed and recreated after configuration change.

Now I pass `ScanCallback` object located in the mainViewModel:

```
    if (mainViewModel.scanActive) {
      bleScanner?.stopScan(mainViewModel.scanCallback)
    } else {
      bleScanner?.startScan(buildScanFilters(), buildScanSettings(), mainViewModel.scanCallback)
    }
```

I checked the references using `Log.d` and they were indeed the same objects located at the same memory location even after configuration change. However doing this didn't help. Scanning didn't stop, I was still receving the callbacks.

So I thought, maybe `BluetoothAdapter` and `BluetoothLeScanner` variables are also not allowed to be recreated and their references must be kept the same.

At this point I don't know how to proceed further, because if I move these two variables into a `ViewModel`, there's an error that no Context is provided to `getSystemService()` function, probably because I'm calling it not from an Activity. And as I understand, moving Bluetooth-related objects to `ViewModel` is not recommended anyway.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Solved this issue my retrieving `BluetoothManager` from Application `Context`, instead of Activity `Context`.

```
  private val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? by lazy {
    val bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager =
     applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
    bluetoothManager.adapter
  }
```

This seemed to work. `ScanCallback` object still needs to be placed in the `ViewModel` though. Couldn't think of anything better.

Comment: The `BluetoothAdapter` and `BluetoothLeScanner` objects are singletons, so you can re-obtain a reference to these whenever you want and do not need to store the reference.

Comment: @Emil hi, sorry if didn't understand your comment, I'm new to android coding. I checked the references of `BluetoothManager`, `BluetoothAdapter` and `BluetoothLeScanner` before and after configuration change and they are different. For example, `android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager@d626111` before and `android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager@de98ef9` after.

Comment: They are probably different, because on configuration change `Activity` is destroyed and recreated, and so its `Context` also recreated. And `BluetoothManager` is tied to a `Context`, so this is why they are recreated.